# sqlite3_prepare_v2 returns OK on iPhone and iPad mini devices, but with error on normal iPad device

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm facing a problem in this code: it's working ok on iPhone and iPad Mini, but it's giving the error message on the big iPad. Is there any reason?

Code:

```
- (sqlite3_stmt *)executeQuery:(char *)aQuery {
    NSString *dbPath = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kDBPath];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;
    sqlite3 *database;
    if (sqlite3_open((char *)[dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, aQuery, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            //Here is the point: on iPad Mini and iPhone it works fine, but on the normal iPad it can't execute this query
            NSLog(@"Error on SQL - (sqlite3_stmt *)executeWithReturn:(char *)aQuery");
            statement = NULL;
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error on Open database");
    }
    return statement;
}
```

Prints from LLDB:

```
(lldb) print (BOOL)[[NSFileManager defaultManager] isWritableFileAtPath:dbPath]
(BOOL) $0 = YES
(lldb) print (char *)aQuery
(char *) $1 = 0x1f0a1000 "select CodAplicacao, CodLocalidade, Nome, Desc, DataCriacao, Editando from Aplicacao_en"
```

Any ideas?

Regards!

**EDIT:**

It's getting the error "database disk image is malformed". I couldn't find in the internet how to fix it.

Comment: See revised answer re "Database disk image is malformed".

Answer (score 2):

In your revised question, you inform us that `sqlite3_errmsg` is reporting "database disk image is malformed". This is a sign that your database has been corrupted. This can happen if your app crashed while doing some database operation at some previous date.

You can confirm this by running the following SQL:

```
PRAGMA integrity_check;
```

If you want to go through that process, you can copy the database from your device back to your Mac (using Xcode's Organizer and go to the "Devices" section) and then use your Mac SQLite database tool of choice (worst case, the command line `sqlite3` program) and then run the previous `PRAGMA` command. You can even perform this programmatically (it returns a result set like a `SELECT` statement).

Thing is, we're fairly confident that it's going to report problems. The easy fix is to rebuild the database (e.g. delete the database and if you originally copied it from the bundle, do that again, if you programmatically created it, repeat that process).

If you're determined to try to recover user data from the database, you can contemplate following the process outlined in [Sergei Dorogin's technical blog - SQLiteException "database disk image is malformed"](http://techblog.dorogin.com/2011/05/sqliteexception-database-disk-image-is.html). He wrote that for a different platform, but the basic process is probably applicable here. Thing is, that unless you absolutely need to recover user data, that process is probably unnecessary.

So, in short, your database on that device is corrupted and you need to rebuild it. Just delete the app (in case your database is in the `Documents` folder, you need to delete app to empty out that folder) and reinstall the app and you should be good.

---

Change your log statement from:

```
NSLog(@"Error on SQL - (sqlite3_stmt *)executeWithReturn:(char *)aQuery");
```

to

```
NSLog(@"Error on SQL - %s: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
```

That should give you an informative error message that tells you what's wrong.

Generally, these sorts of problems result from version of the database on that particular device. It is extremely unlikely to be related to the device itself.

Perhaps your app created a blank database at some point and thus the table is not found. If you use Xcode's Organizer, go to the "Devices" section, and you can copy the app folders to your Mac and then examine the database on your Mac and see if you confirm that the database is as you expected it to be.

Comment: Good, it helped me to find what is the exactly error, but I still can't solve it

Comment: I have done before what said, but my database was ok according to PRAGMA integrity_check. I made a coppy too, but it didn't work

Comment: @Claudio - Fascinating. You you're saying you did `PRAGMA integrity_check` on that database (the one in `Documents`, presumably, not the pristine one you might have sitting in the bundle), but when you perform the SQL that your app does, you still get this "database disk image is malformed" error? While I find that quite surprising, I think the prognosis, to rebuild the database (presumably by deleting app and starting over), still applies.